# can't block wifi and other communication on windows 11

Tags: windows-11

I am looking for a way to block and restore communication using commands as an ordinary user in windows 11. netsh command requires admin rights and cannot be used. changing firewall settings in windows defender also requires admin rights and cannot be used. I am looking for a way to do this. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Changes to your wireless (turn on and off and block communications) require Admin Credentials. The same for Windows Defender and Firewall changes for other communication

Get the organization that has the credentials to make the changes required.

They can make batch files to disable / enable wireless and set these files so you can run them.

There is not any other way to do this.